# Prof of Thm 7.26 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Thm 7.26 of Baby Rudin, there is a sentence right after equation (51) saying:

$P_n(x)=\int_{-1}^1f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt$ is clearly a polynomial in $x$...

Here $f$ is a function and $Q_n$ is a polynomial. How so? I can't see why that must be the case...

Answer (score 5):

In my version of Rudin's book, we have
$$P_n(x)=\int_{-x}^{1-x}f(x+t)Q_n(t)dt=\int_0^1f(t)Q_n(t-x)dt$$
where we do a change of variables in the second equality.

Note that $Q_n$ is polynomial, so $Q_n(t-x)$ is polynomial in $x$, with coefficients being polynomials in $t$. Thus $f(t)Q_n(t-x)$ is a polynomials in $x$, with coefficients depending on $t$. The integrals act only on the coefficients, so we end up with a polynomial in $x$.

---

More precisely, if we write $Q_n(t-x)=\sum a_i(t)x^i$, where $a_i$ are polynomials, we obtain
$$P_n(x)=\sum\left(\int_0^1f_n(t)a_i(t)dt\right)x^i,$$
a polynomial in $x$.

Comment: A prankster might ask why this (or other) "integrals of polynomials..." would be polynomials. :) Not that I doubt the conclusion, nor the intuitiveness of it! :)